# Tomcat Started/Stopped with errors, return code: 1

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat Started/Stopped with errors, return code: 1
Make sure you have Java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free
Check the "/xampp/tomcat/logs" folder for more information

I have already made a JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME. It still says the same error. What should I do?

Comment: You should _make sure you have Java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free. And check the "/xampp/tomcat/logs" folder for more information_ ;) . Also, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [help/on-topic]. There's not enough information here and it doesn't look programming related based on your information